# Sort with field separator

Tags: linux, sort

I'm trying to sort the `/etc/passwd` numerically by user id numbersb(third field) in ascending order and then send it to s4.

What command would I uses to do that? I'm on this for a while now.

Comment: What have [you been trying](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/473193/edit)? It may be useful for someone to explain not only what does work, but also why what you'd tried didn't work.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try the below code, Sort the `/etc/passwd` based on uid.

```
sort -n -t ':' -k3 /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your command. I used a different command, but I think you one will work.

Comment: consider adding how this command works.

Answer (score 4):

There is a specific command for sorting the `/etc/passwd` file by UID:

```
# pwck -s
```

Just to be safe, you should use this instead of generic `sort` if you're sorting the actual, active `/etc/passwd` file for your system, as `pwck` will handle the necessary file locking correctly. Otherwise strange things might happen if someone attempted to log in or even query some user information while you're replacing the /etc/passwd file.